# "Take a whole day up." What does it mean

Tags: meaning, clauses

What is the meaning of:

> to take a whole day up.

Answer (score 3):

The expression, "to take up" with a time period means to occupy that time period, or to use it up.

Examples:

> "Cleaning up this mess is going to take up the whole day."
>
> "Almost half of my vacation was taken up by bus rides."
>
> "I wish you wouldn't take up my time with this petty stuff."

But I think it is unusual to separate the word "up" from "take" as it appears in your example. Usually people would rearrange it and say, "to take up a whole day."

Comment: would the sentence "Cleaning up this mess is going **to take the whole day.**" be correct as well?

Comment: Yes, certainly. "Take *up*" just emphasizes a tiny bit more the idea that the the whole day is going to be completely occupied by cleanup, and nothing else will be accomplished.